# Fetch database value automatically without the input of user

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am making a page which fetch all my database value. I want the page to get the value of Driver_id and Vehicle_id automatically from the database, users need to know what's the id and key in themselves. But I am stuck at here.

Tools im using is phpMyAdmin.

For which below is my code of the table:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<style>
<table>
    <th>Vehicle ID</th>
    <th>Vehicle Model</th>
    <th>Vehicle Color</th>
    <th>Plate Number</th>
    <th>Seats</th>
    <th>Driver ID</th>
    <th> </th>
<?php 
    $link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","jomsewa");

    mysqli_select_db($link,"jomsewa") or die(mysqli_error($link));

    $select = "SELECT * FROM vehicle";

    $row = mysqli_query($link,$select);

    while ($array = mysqli_fetch_array($row)){
        echo "<tr><td>".$array['Vehicle_id']."</td>
                    <td>".$array['Vehicle_model']."</td>
                    <td>".$array['Vehicle_color']."</td>
                    <td>".$array['Vehicle_model']."</td>
                    <td>".$array['Vehicle_seats']."</td>
                    <td>".$array['Driver_id']."</td>
                    <td><a href='Dmaintenance.php?Driverid=".$array['Driver_id']."'>Select</a></td>"."</tr>";
    }

    mysqli_close($link);
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The link is linked to Dmaintenance.php:

```
<?php
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","jomsewa"); 
if (!$link) 
{ 
echo "Failed to connect to database: " . mysqli_connect_error(); 
}
mysqli_select_db($link,"jomsewa") or die(mysqli_error($link));
?>
<h3>Please update your maintenance details in the form below.</h3>
<form action="maintenance.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Vehicle Maintenance Information:</legend>
    <table cellpadding="10">
    <tr>
        <td>
                <?php 
        if(isset($GET['Driver_id']))
                 {
           $txt = $GET['Driver_id'];
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                 {
            echo "<td>".$row['Vehicle_id']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['Driver_id']."</td>";
             }

            }?></td>
       </tr>
```

What i want is when click on one particular row link on the next page it must display my selected row contents automatically.

Comment: in `Dmaintenance.php` you will need a new sql query that uses a `where` clause with the relevant variable as the value, using a prepared statement of course. Currently it does not appear there is any SQL statement / query on that page

Comment: the PHP generated HTML, in the table, is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$_GET['Driverid]` instead of `$_GET['Driver_id]`

There is no SQL query on `Dmaintenance.php` to fetch row based on `Driverid`. There should be

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM vehicle WHERE Vehicle_id=".$_GET['Driverid'];
$row = mysqli_query($link,$query);

while ($array = mysqli_fetch_array($row)){
  print_r($array);
}
```

For example

```
<a href="Dmaintenance.php?Driverid=123">Click Here</a>
```

and only use following in `Dmaintenance.php`, you will see the parameter value

```
if(isset($_GET['Driverid'])){
 echo $_GET['Driverid'];
}
```

Comment: Is the Driver_id following the column name in the database? if thats the case, should i use $_GET['Driver_id']?

Comment: @JiasoonLoo you have building url Dmaintenance.php?Driverid=, so here parameter is Driverid

Comment: I tried changing it to Driverid, but it's still not working. I tried to use echo $_GET['Driverid'] to see if the parameter has any value but i got this error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Module4\Module4\Module4\Dmaintenance.php on line 46

Comment: @JiasoonLoo I have updated solution for better understanding

Comment: Sorry i fixed the syntax error, I got undefined index error:
Notice: Undefined index: Driverid in C:\xampp\htdocs\Module4\Module4\Module4\Dmaintenance.php on line 44

Comment: Thank you so much I have got the value now.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever dealing with user supplied data, as you are in `Dmaintenance.php`, you need to take extra precautions to ensure that your scripts are not rendered vulnerable to SQL injection or other nasty surprises. In this instance because you are using user supplied data directly in your SQL ( or would be if you adopt the style of query given by @Rakesh where you directly embed the GET data into the query ) the SQL is vulnerable to `SQL Injection` and could spell disaster.

The following shows how you might use `prepared statements` to help avoid sql injection. There are liberal comments throughout, hope it helps.

```
<?php
    /*********************
        Dmaintenance.php
    *********************/
    try{
        /*

            encapsulate everything within a `TRY/CATCH` block
            so that you can throw your own Exceptions if needed.

            The db methods here are using OO methods because 
            they are less verbose and, imo, easier to read/remember.
        */
        $link=new mysqli( 'localhost', 'root', '', 'jomsewa' );

        if( $link ){

            /* The `driver_id` is vital for the query to be run */
            $id=!empty( $_GET['Driverid'] ) ? $_GET['Driverid'] : false;

            if( $id ){
                /* 
                    create a general SELECT statement to 
                    return specific fields. The reason for
                    doing this is because we bind the query
                    results directly to PHP variables using
                    `bind_result` later
                */
                $sql='select `Vehicle_id`, `Vehicle_model`, `Vehicle_color`, `Vehicle_seats`
                        from `vehicle` 
                      where `driver_id`=?';

                /* create the prepared statement */
                $stmt=$link->prepare( $sql );


                if( $stmt ){
                    $stmt->bind_param( 's', $id );
                    $res=$stmt->execute();

                    if( $res ){
                        /*
                            Query succeeded - process recordset
                        */

                        $stmt->store_result();
                        $stmt->bind_result( $vid, $model, $colour, $seats );

                        /* open form & table */
                        echo "
                        <h3>Please update your maintenance details in the form below.</h3>
                        <form action='maintenance.php' method='post'>
                            <fieldset>
                                <legend>Vehicle Maintenance Information:</legend>
                                <table cellpadding='10'>"; # padding should be done in CSS and there should be a unit here, probably px

                        /* add dynamic data from db query */
                        while( $stmt->fetch() ){
                            echo "
                            <tr>
                                <td>$vid</td>
                                <td>$model</td>
                                <td>$colour</td>
                                <td>$seats</td>
                            </tr>";
                        }


                        /* close the table */   
                        echo "  
                                </table>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>";



                        $stmt->free_result();
                        $stmt->close();

                    } else {
                        throw new Exception('Query failed');
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new Exception('Failed to prepare SQL');
                }
            } else {
                throw new Exception('No driver id');
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception('No database connection made');
        }
    }catch( Exception $e ){
        exit( $e->getMessage() );
    }
?>
```

The use of `try/catch` above allows you to specify your own messages if/when you encounter problems with the flow through the programme. If you use things like `mysqli_error($link)` to depict an error in production code you unintentionally reveal potentially sensitive information about your server / app than you should.